# ASP Login Control Reset Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, login-control

I have a login control and I have added a reset button to it by converting it into a template. I also tried to empty the text using the Find Control Method. But I cannot empty the textboxes. Html and Codebehind below

Code:

```
 <asp:Login ID="lgnLogin" runat="server" MembershipProvider = "myCustomProvider" OnAuthenticate = "lgnLogin_Authenticate" DisplayRememberMe = "false" TitleText = "" UserNameLabelText = "Username" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                    ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="lgnLogin">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                    ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="lgnLogin">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="resetButton" runat="server" Text="Reset" 
                                    onclick="resetButton_Click"/>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                                    ValidationGroup="lgnLogin" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox username =  (TextBox)lgnLogin.FindControl("UserName");
        TextBox passsword = (TextBox)lgnLogin.FindControl("Password");

        username.Text = "";
        passsword.Text = "";

    }
```

Comment: This is .NET not ASP Classic.

Comment: Maybe your browser has remembered username and password. add autocomplete="off" inside your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the HTML reset?

http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms13.htm

Answer (score 1):

The password should clear automatically on postback anyway but the UserName is stored in the controls ViewState and repopulates the Textbox after your event has fired so you also need to clear the username field like this -

```
lgnLogin.UserName = "";
```

That should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference and to whoever this might concern in the future; All you have to do is the following, from your codebehind:

**C#**

```
protected void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)lgnLogin.FindControl("UserName")).Text = "";
    username.Text = "";
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
 CType(LoginAuth.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox).Text = ""
 LoginAuth.UserName = ""
```

The password textbox gets cleared automatically. It seems we need to set both the UserName.Text and Login.UserName to an empty string as I have done above.

Have a good day!